# Помогите написать логику сценария для jmeter, kafka

Tags: jmeter, apache-kafka

Нужно написать логику сценария, чтобы продюсер отправлял запрос.
А консьюмер читал топик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В смысле "помогите"? С такими запросами вам на [upwork](https://www.upwork.com/) или [fiverr](https://www.fiverr.com/)

Тут отвечают на вопросы, а это значит что вы должны сами сначала что-то попробовать сделать, а если это вдруг почему-то не получится - то спросить почему это не работает: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В виде исключения:

1. Примерный код для отправки сообщения в Kafka

   ```
   import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
   import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord

   def props = new Properties()
   props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:29092")
   props.put("acks", "all")
   props.put("retries", 0)
   props.put("batch.size", 16384)
   props.put("linger.ms", 1)
   props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432)
   props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
   props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")


   def producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props)

   producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>('foo', '{"order": "' + UUID.randomUUID() + '", "value1": 5, "value2": 3}'))

   producer.close()
   ```
2. Примерный код для чтения сообщения из Kafka и записи в файл
   import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
   import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer

   ```
   def props = new Properties()
   props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:29092")
   props.put("acks", "all")
   props.put("retries", 0)
   props.put("batch.size", 16384)
   props.put("linger.ms", 1)
   props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432)
   props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
   props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
   props.put("group.id", "foo")


   def consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props)
   consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList('foo'))
   ConsumerRecord record = consumer.poll(1000).first()

   def value = new JsonSlurper().parseText(record.value())

   def uuid = value.order
   def value1 = value.value1
   def value2 = value.value2

   def sum = value1 + value2

   new File('your-file.txt') << 'order_' << uuid << ' SUMM ' << sum

   consumer.close()
   ```

Материалы:

- [Send and receive JSON objects with Kafka java client](https://medium.com/@asce4s/send-and-receive-json-objects-with-kafka-java-client-41bfbb4de108)
- [Kafka Java Client](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-clients/java/current/overview.html)
- [How to Do Kafka Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/kafka-testing)